# Running scripts without downloading chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to know the easiest way to run the Python script on another computer.
I can compile a script in exe through PyInstaller and cx_Freeze. 
How can this be done without changing the script path (`driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\py\chromedriver'))` to ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 1):

Generally we will place all the required drivers in the project and then provide the path to the driver in the project. something like this below

```
project
   drivers
   tests
   any other folders
```

Now you can access place all the drivers in the `drivers` folder and access them as below.

```
def get_full_path_to_folder(folderName):
    folders = os.path.abspath(os.pardir).split(os.sep)
    folderPath = ''
    for folder in folders:
        if folderPath == '':
            folderPath = folder
        else:
            folderPath = folderPath + "\\" +folder
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folderPath, folderName)):
            return os.path.join(folderPath, folderName)
            break

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(get_full_path_to_folder('drivers'), "chromedriver.exe"))
```

By this way drivers will go with the .exe that you are planning.